# Rails tutorial - displaying username instead of user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the Rails Tutorial there is a great chapter on creating a toy app with users and microposts. However, when editing the microposts, I can only edit user_id which is a numeric value, not user name. Is there a simple way to enforce displaying user's name instead of user's id in the app?
I've looked app/views/microposts/_form.html.erb and it says:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :user_id %><br>
<%= f.number_field :user_id %>
</div>
```

What should I change to be able to select the users by name instead of the id?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a select helper rather than a `number_field`.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :first_name) %>
```

In your controller, you'd need the following line (or something similar):

```
@users = User.all
```

If you want to display each user's full name, you'd need to create a method in user.rb to concatenate first and last names, like so:

```
def fullname
    fullname = "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
end
```

Your select would then use the method name, like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :fullname) %>
```

You should probably take some time to read up on all the different [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is called a `collection_select`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

```
f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :username
```